# How to create Gridview click menu in fragment?

Tags: android, gridview

I create a ViewPager with PageLineIndicator and ViewPager contain three Fragments(FragmentA,FragmentB,FragmentC) and it's working.

Now I want to create gridview Button click menu in FragmentA which is on click position in gridview called next fragmentB and if I click next position then called FragmentC.

Here below is code of viewpager which we create:

MainActivity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

import com.viewpagerindicator.LinePageIndicator;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    FragmentAdapter mAdapter;
    ViewPager mPager;
    LinePageIndicator mIndicator;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAdapter = new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mIndicator = (LinePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);

    }

    public void switchToFragmentA(){
        mPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    }
    public void switchToFragementB(){
        mPager.setCurrentItem(1);
    }
    public void switchToFragmentC(){
        mPager.setCurrentItem(2);
    }


}
```

fragmentAdapter

```
package com.demo.demoproject;

import com.viewpagerindicator.IconPagerAdapter;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class FragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements IconPagerAdapter{

    public FragmentAdapter(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(supportFragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconResId(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
        switch(position){
        case 0:
            fragment = new FragmentA();
            break;

        case 1:
            fragment = new FragmentB();
            break;

        case 2:
            fragment = new FragmentC();
            break;

        }

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 3;
    }

}
```

FragmentA

```
package com.demo.demoproject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;


public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

    GridView gridView;
    ArrayList<Item> gridArray = new ArrayList<Item>();
    CustomGridViewAdapter customGridAdapter;

    public FragmentA() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);

        /*Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).switchToFragmentB();

            }
        });*/

        Bitmap homeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                R.drawable.home);
        Bitmap userIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                R.drawable.personal);

        gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon, "Home"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(userIcon, "User"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon, "House"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(userIcon, "Friend"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon, "Home"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(userIcon, "Personal"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon, "Home"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(userIcon, "User"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon, "Building"));

        gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        customGridAdapter = new CustomGridViewAdapter(getActivity(),
                R.layout.row_grid, gridArray);
        gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).switchToFragementB();
                    break;

                case 1:
                    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).switchToFragmentC();
                    break;


                }
            }

        });

        return view;
    }



}
```

CustomGridViewAdapter class

```
package com.demo.demoproject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomGridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    ArrayList<Item> data = new ArrayList<Item>();

    public CustomGridViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
            ArrayList<Item> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        RecordHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new RecordHolder();
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
            holder.imageItem = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (RecordHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        Item item = data.get(position);
        holder.txtTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
        holder.imageItem.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());
        return row;

    }

    static class RecordHolder {
        TextView txtTitle;
        ImageView imageItem;

    }
}
```

Item class

```
package com.demo.demoproject;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

/**
 * 
 * @author manish.s
 *
 */

public class Item {
    Bitmap image;
    String title;

    public Item(Bitmap image, String title) {
        super();
        this.image = image;
        this.title = title;
    }
    public Bitmap getImage() {
        return image;
    }
    public void setImage(Bitmap image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }


}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >




    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <com.viewpagerindicator.LinePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:padding="5dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_a.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     android:paddingTop="70dp" >

    <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView1"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:columnWidth="90dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

row_grid.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="15sp" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

this code for navigate in main_activity..

in main Activity

```
public void switchToFragmentA(){
        mPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    }
    public void switchToFragementB(){
        mPager.setCurrentItem(1);
    }
    public void switchToFragmentC(){
        mPager.setCurrentItem(2);
    }
```

And call it from FragmentA

```
FragmentA class
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).switchToFragementB();
                    break;

                case 1:
                    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).switchToFragmentC();
                    break;


                }
            }

        });
```

Comment: Hi, What i understood from you is , in your first fragment A, If you click on gridview  position say 0 then it shoud navigate to B. then if you click on position say 1 then again navigate to fragment C. right??

Comment: right same as u told me

Comment: hello sir, Right now i create a gridview in fragmentA But Now problem is that when i click on gridview position say 1 then its navigate to fragmentC and when i come back to fragmentA then my menu is increases double automatically why ???

Comment: could you please paste your code, Ie gridveiw and its navigation?

Comment: ya check my edited code above..

Comment: just i upload my full code..

Comment: Write your entire navigation code in your fragment A itself... Do not write anything on MainActivity. then instead of position try to use Items[postion] iff based on if you want to navigate according to your contents in Items. Otherwise position is fine

Comment: i used this in my main activity =public void switchToFragmentA(){
  mPager.setCurrentItem(0);
 }
 public void switchToFragementB(){
  mPager.setCurrentItem(1);
 }
 public void switchToFragmentC(){
  mPager.setCurrentItem(2);
 }

Comment: and call this in my fragmentA class by this code..gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
     int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
     ((MainActivity) getActivity()).switchToFragementB();
     break;

    case 1:
     ((MainActivity) getActivity()).switchToFragmentC();
     break;
    

    }
   }

  });

Comment: check above i added entire navigate code in my fragmentA

Comment: Use Intent to navigate from one fragment to another fragment

Comment: I used intent in my FragmentA but app is not running...

Comment: can u please write code this code..